# Is it transactionTotal or transactionRevenue in Google eCommerce datalayer?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm seeing Google documentation pages with both. 
I want to know which one I should use:
transactionTotal (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169) 
or
transactionRevenue (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce)

Comment: For enhanced ecommerce it's revenue. TransactionTotal is used by standard ecommerce (old ecommerce)

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I also understood it depends on whether you use GTM or GA scripts on your website.